# How to change Empty Table Style: Element UI?

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

Now, If the table is empty then "Text = 暂无数据" is coming. I want to change it. Want to give an Image and two buttons.

How is this possible?

```
<el-table
  :data="tableData">
  <el-table-column
      label="Name"
  >
  </el-table-column>
</el-table>
```

Vue.js:

```
data() {
    return {
      isActive: true,
      tableData: [],
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Easy way to `display: none;` to that block.

```
.el-table__empty-block {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Then you will be able to `append()` what you want with `slot`

```
<el-table>
<div slot="append" v-if="tableData.length=='0'">
  // You can add what you want
</div>
</el-table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check [empty-text](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html#table-attributes) attribute.

Example:

```html
<el-table :data="[]" :empty-text="'Downloading company data...'"></el-table>
```